# iOS Facebook get user's e-mail

Tags: ios, facebook, email, sdk

I tried over 2000 things to get the user's email. I can't get it from the Facebook SDK's graph API. It doesn't contain email property. I also tried to add manually the email property to the FB framework and nothing happened. Is it possible to download the first FB SDK which is compatible with iOS 7? Does it still have the email property, doesn't it? Or is there any other way how to get the REAL email, I must work with them. I don't need the example@facebook.com.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"email", @"public_profile"];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }


            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commsDidLogin:)]) {
                [delegate commsDidLogin:NO];
            }
        } else {
            if (user.isNew) {
                NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
            }

            [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    PFUser *usere = [PFUser currentUser];
                    [usere setObject:[result objectForKey:@"first_name"] forKey:@"name"];
                    [usere setObject:[result objectForKey:@"last_name"] forKey:@"surname"];
                 //   [usere setObject:[result objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"mail"];
                    [usere saveEventually];
                     NSLog(@"user info: %@", result);
                        }
            }];

                }
                if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commsDidLogin:)]) {
                    [delegate commsDidLogin:YES];
                }
            }];
        }
```

Comment: The email address will only be returned if it's a verified email address.

Comment: [FBRequest requestForMe] gives all information with email also.. I set permissions @"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown". I have fetched by this in new facebook sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not code for graph API,

but with new facebook sdk version 3, I have code for that.

```
-(void)openFbSession
{
    [[self appDelegate].session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    NSArray *permissions =     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown",nil];
    [self appDelegate].session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];

    [[self appDelegate].session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                            FBSessionState status,
                                                            NSError *error) {
        if(!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"success");
            [self myFbInfo];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"failure");
        }

    }];
}
```

and for all information, myFbInfo method is

```
-(void)myFbInfo
{
    [FBSession setActiveSession:[self appDelegate].session];

    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle error
        }

        else {
            //NSString *userName = [FBuser name];
            //NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [FBuser id]];
            NSLog(@"Name : %@",[FBuser name]);
            NSLog(@"first name : %@",[FBuser first_name]);
            NSLog(@"Last name : %@",[FBuser last_name]);
            NSLog(@"ID : %@",[FBuser id]);
            NSLog(@"username : %@",[FBuser username]);
            NSLog(@"Email : %@",[FBuser objectForKey:@"email"]);

            NSLog(@"user all info : %@",FBuser);

              }
    }];

}
```

---

EDIT

---

in appdelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;
```

in appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation
{
    //NSLog(@"FB or Linkedin clicked");
    return [self.session handleOpenURL:url];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.session close];
}
```

Comment: And how did you defined appDelegate property?

Answer (score 1):

You have to request permissions first, as descibed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#button-permissions

After that, you can request the user's information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#userinfo

Comment: Check my Edit, please. I did it in this way, but if I run my app I get error to the line with email(the comment in my code).

Comment: Does the Graph API Explorer return an email for the same user as you're testing your app with? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&version=v2.0

Comment: Graph API Explorer return just id and name. Email field is empty or disallowed by the access token.

Comment: Well, you can request an Access Token with the appropriate permissions by clicking "Get Access Token" and select `email` under extended permissions. Confirm and run the query again then...

Answer (score 0):

You can't just get the user's email address, you must ask them for permission to do so. Take a look at this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

Facebook Connect will allow the passing of `scope=email` in the `get` string of your auth call.

Comment: I know, I have already set permission. It even ask user in fb dialog to confirm them. But how to get the property I want to use?

Comment: The array call (`$facebook->getLoginUrl( array('scope' => 'email,read_stream'));`) should save the email in an array. The array is the access point for that, as well as the username etc.

Comment: I have no idea, what do you mean. Have some code in ios to explain? Never worked with php before.

Comment: I'm fairly inexperienced myself. When I look at that code, my impression is that it creates an array called `scope` which contains all the credentials that you request.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work with above examples. I solved it using a more complex call to FBSDKGraphRequest..

In viewDidLoad:

```
if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {

  println("Logged in to FB")
  self.returnUserData()  //Specified here below

} else {
  print("Not logged in to FB")

  let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
  loginView.center = self.view.center
  loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
  loginView.delegate = self
  self.view.addSubview(loginView)
  }
}
```

Read permissions above is important to be able to get it later on when you request from FB server.

Remember to conform to the "FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate" protocols by including the functions needed (not included here).

To be able to fetch email etc. I use the more complex call for the graphRequest and specify the accesstoken and the parameters (se below).

```
 let fbAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString   

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(
    graphPath: "me", 
    parameters: ["fields":"email,name"], 
    tokenString: fbAccessToken, 
    version: nil, 
    HTTPMethod: "GET")
```

... and in the same function execute with completionHandler:

```
graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> () in result

  if ((error) != nil) {
    // Process error
    println("Error: \(error)")
  } else {
    println("fetched user: \(result)")
  }
}
```

Works beautifully!

And additionally.. parameters are found listed here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Answer (score 0):

```
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
            // Do work
            NSLog(@"%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);

            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me" parameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"picture.type(large),id,email,name,gender" forKey:@"fields"] tokenString:result.token.tokenString version:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error) {

                         NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

                     }
                 }];
            }

        }
```