# how to fetch facebook user email id for iOS application?

Tags: ios, facebook, email

I have integrated facebook SDK latest version. I followed every steps by facebook docs. I have given permissions as follows 
in viewdidload method

```
loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
self->loginview.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"user_friends",@"email"];
```

but for some people accounts, fetching email id, for some people accounts not. I have searched somany forums but not helped me, I have tried changed settings for privacy page for email id access to everyone, but still not geting user email id. I was printed user permissions in my NSLog, suppose if i am getting email id in that time, permissions showing (installed, public profile, email,user_friends), if i am not getting email id that time its showing permissions as (public profile, installed). Really bothering for this from morning onwards. Where should i change code in my application or user facebook profile settings. Please give your valuable suggestions. Thanks

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890798/ios-facebook-get-users-e-mail/24911095#24911095

Comment: hi Max thanks for your quick reply, and where your are getting public profile information in that permissions in your code?

Comment: first try that, if worked then why should you need that?

Comment: MAX, i said in my query description, i am getting public profile information except email id, because i need user info to send server of mine, by the way i am trying your code !

Comment: public profile is a permission required.. if you want than add it also  in my code. It worked fine with this also. I have checked before.

Comment: a) users can decline to grant certain permissions to your app. b) not every user _has_ an email on file with Facebook (f.e. when they signed up for FB using their mobile phone).

Comment: first thanks for your quick reply MR.CBroe, i am checking with some of my friends accounts also which have email and given permission to access, but still i am not fetching the email ids of them